# Getting rid of Samsung's Gallery app notifications? (or even the entire app)

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5, gallery, disable-app

I'm currently using a Galaxy S5 mini with Android 5.1.1 and one thing that I find particularly irritating is Samsung's Gallery app that keeps giving notifications. For some reason I can't seem to turn them off.

There appears to be no setting in the Gallery app itself to disable it. And I cannot disable or remove or uninstall the app itself.

If I go to Android settings, Sounds and Notifications, Application Notifications, for most apps in the list I can block the notifications. Strangely enough this is not the case with a few built-in apps like Gallery:

[image: screenshot]

I also looked in the Application settings for Gallery, unfortunately the "Show notifications" checkbox and the "Disable" button are both disabled.

Is there any way to get rid of Gallery's notifications, or rather just get rid of the app entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallery is a stock app, you can uninstall it without root by following this guide on XDA.

Link
https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/